# when I practise the Mxnet turorial mnist, an error"ImportError: No module named mnist_demo" occurs

Tags: python, mxnet

The tutorial is on http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/mnist.html.
At this step:
"

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import cv2
import numpy as np
from mnist_demo import html, script
def classify(img):
    img = img[len('data:image/png;base64,'):].decode('base64')
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(img, np.uint8), -1)
    img = cv2.resize(img[:,:,3], (28,28))
    img = img.astype(np.float32).reshape((1,1,28,28))/255.0
    return model.predict(img)[0].argmax()

'''
To see the model in action, run the demo notebook at
https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/master/python/tutorials/mnist.ipynb.
'''
HTML(html + script)
```

### "

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      2 import cv2
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from mnist_demo import html, script
      5 def classify(img):
      6     img = img[len('data:image/png;base64,'):].decode('base64')

```
ImportError: No module named mnist_demo
```

---

I do not know what is the reason and I cannot find the answer on Google.
Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because the tutorial was not written in a single file. You should put the `mnist_demo.py` file together with your the tutorial notebook. The file could be found at [mxnet-notebooks](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/tree/master/python/tutorials) on the github site.
:P

Comment: Eh, it was 8 days ago when you posted the question. I guess you must have already solved it.